# How to use Nullable variable in generic method

Tags: c#

This is a method in an interface. It gives me an error that I can't make my string nullable (string?), but why? My method will return an IEnumerable no matter what.

```
IEnumerable<Cars> GetAvailableCars(Vendor carVendor, string? someAdditionalInfo);
```

Comment: Because `string` is a reference type, so it's already nullable?

Comment: `string?` requires C# 8.0. This is unrelated to generics.